# How can I change views' rotation based on user's scroll in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, picker

I've implemented this wheel picker:

[image: my current example]

but I don't know how to change numbers' angulation according to wheel rotation, what should I do?

I would like to achieve this:

[image: right example]

Numbers' rotation should be based on user's scroll(for example, every number should be in normal position when reaches the top)

This is the full code:

```
struct myVal : Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    let val : String
}

enum Direction {
    case left
    case right
}

struct WheelView: View {
    // Circle Radius
    @State var radius : Double = 150
    // Direction of swipe
    @State var direction = Direction.left
    // index of the number at the bottom of the circle
    @State var chosenIndex = 0
    // degree of circle and hue
    @Binding var degree : Double
//    @State var degree = 90.0
    let array : [myVal]
    let circleSize : Double
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            let anglePerCount = Double.pi * 2.0 / Double(array.count)
            let drag = DragGesture()
                .onEnded { value in
                    if value.startLocation.x > value.location.x + 10 {
                        direction = .left
                    } else if value.startLocation.x < value.location.x - 10 {
                        direction = .right
                    }
                   //here I call the function to move the wheel
                }
          // MARK: WHEEL STACK - BEGINNING
            ZStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< array.count) { index in
                    let angle = Double(index) * anglePerCount
                    let xOffset = CGFloat(radius * cos(angle))
                    let yOffset = CGFloat(radius * sin(angle))
                    Text("\(array[index].val)")
                        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -degree))
                        .offset(x: xOffset, y: yOffset )
                }
            }
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: degree))
            .gesture(drag)
            .onAppear() {
                radius = circleSize/2 - 30 // 30 is for padding
            }
           // MARK: WHEEL STACK - END
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you lay each one out, starting from 0, rotate 30degrees for each one compounding it. 360 / 12 = 30. I'm assuming you can have up to 360 values so truly you'd need to rotate `360 / n  = rotation amount`

Comment: @xTwisteDx I did it in my moveWheel function, I'll show you an image of it to let you understand better: [Image](https://i.imgur.com/w2ZwDoD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating angle in radian. Set radians instead of degrees and add `Double.pi/2`.

```
Text("\(array[index].val)")
     .rotationEffect(Angle(radians: angle + Double.pi/2)) // <== Here
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much it works fine, I was missing that I had to change degrees with radians, can you also suggest me what I can do if I want to change the zero from bottom to top?(Cause right now I start spinning from the bottom, on zero), I would like to start with zero from the top and then proceed clockwise

Comment: For this just set your initial degree ```var degree : Double = -90```